# Electric charge in stable equilibrium

Tags: equilibrium

Why an electric charge can't be held in a position of stable equilibrium, neither by an electrostatic field nor by a mechanical force ?

Comment: can you add more to your question please to make it clearer - are you thinking in general or about a particular situation? It would help if you could indicate what you think about this.

Comment: I do not think your statement is correct

Comment: Why not stable equilibrium? Put the charge in an electric field that would attract it upwards with an force equal to the gravitational attraction by the earth, and the charge will remain suspended in the air.

Comment: @Sofia, this is not stable equilibrium. This is neutral equilibrium. Check [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mechanical_equilibrium).

Answer (score 1):

A charged particle will always travel along a field line - negative particles in one direction and positive particles in the other. So to have a point of stable equilibrium you would need converging field lines a bit like this:

[image: Field lines]

So the charged particle, like the red dot, will be attracted to the point where the lines meet then held there.

The trouble is that the divergence at this point is non-zero, and Maxwell's equations tell us you can't have a non-zero divergence unless some charge is present. So you can't just create a field looking like this in the centre of your vacuum chamber.

You can of course create a field like this by putting a large charge in your vacuum chamber. For example a large positive charge acts as a potential minimum for negatively charged objects. Sadly this isn't likely to be useful as your positively and negatively charged objects are likely to interact and spoil your experiment.

Answer (score 0):

Charged particles can be trapped for long periods of time in pureley electrostatic ion traps like the one described in [this publication](http://arxiv.org/abs/1105.0499).

The principle of operation of these electrostatic traps is similar to optical 'traps' in cavity ring down spectroscopy. Two electrostatic lenses are placed opposite each other and if I remember correctly it is organized so that the focal lengths of the lenses are greater than the separation between them.

The charged particles are reflected back and forth continuously between the two electrostatic lenses (or mirrors). The trapped ions are overall in 'stable' equilibrium because they are not ejected by small knocks from their equilibrium trajectories.

The ions in these traps, however, do not remain stationary - they are continuously flying up and down the trap.